# Hide CSS class with jquery

Tags: php, jquery, html, css

I found a post in here that said basically the same thing I'm asking, but it says to "avoid asking for help or clarification", so I'm starting a new post.

I have a server side CSS being generated on a thank you page after an online order submission - it looks like this:

> [image: remove top two lines or hide them]

I would like to hide the text logo - top left - "textLogo1" and then I'd like to hide the "continue shopping" link there in the middle.

I can do this in firebug by adding it to the class, but I'm unable to find the class anywhere.

This is for a site using Big Commerce and I'd like to know:

1. How do you write such a jQuery request?
2. Where would I put said request once written? (header.php I'm assuming)

May I use something like this?

```
document.getElementById('item').className = '';
```

**Some of the code I have so far:**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
<head>
  <title>Thanks for Your Order</title>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="description" content="" />
  <meta name="keywords" content="" />
  <meta name='robots' content='noindex, nofollow' />
  <link href="//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:400,300" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
  <link rel="shortcut icon" href="https://cdn3.bigcommerce.com/s-4xqa0tnsba/product_images/android-icon-48x48.png?t=1496184441" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <script>
    //<![CDATA[
    (function() {
      // this happens before external dependencies (and dom ready) to reduce page flicker
      var node, i;
      for (i = window.document.childNodes.length; i--;) {
        node = window.document.childNodes[i];
        if (node.nodeName == 'HTML') {
          node.className += ' javascript';
        }
      }
    })();
    //]]>
  </script>

  <link href="https://cdn4.bigcommerce.com/r-b894c2cb799bac74ce4990fade5989902a6e1a9d/themes/__master/Styles/styles.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <link href="https://cdn4.bigcommerce.com/r-b894c2cb799bac74ce4990fade5989902a6e1a9d/themes/Stencil/Styles/iselector.css" media="all" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <link href="https://cdn4.bigcommerce.com/r-b894c2cb799bac74ce4990fade5989902a6e1a9d/themes/Stencil/Styles/flexslider.css" media="all" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <link href="https://cdn4.bigcommerce.com/r-b894c2cb799bac74ce4990fade5989902a6e1a9d/themes/Stencil/Styles/slide-show.css" media="all" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <link href="https://cdn4.bigcommerce.com/r-b894c2cb799bac74ce4990fade5989902a6e1a9d/themes/Stencil/Styles/styles-slide-show.css" media="all" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <link href="https://cdn4.bigcommerce.com/r-b894c2cb799bac74ce4990fade5989902a6e1a9d/themes/Stencil/Styles/social.css" media="all" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <link href="https://cdn4.bigcommerce.com/r-b894c2cb799bac74ce4990fade5989902a6e1a9d/themes/Stencil/Styles/styles.css" media="all" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <link href="https://cdn4.bigcommerce.com/r-b894c2cb799bac74ce4990fade5989902a6e1a9d/themes/Stencil/Styles/light.css" media="all" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <link href="https://cdn4.bigcommerce.com/r-b894c2cb799bac74ce4990fade5989902a6e1a9d/themes/Stencil/Styles/theme.css" media="all" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <link href="https://cdn4.bigcommerce.com/r-b894c2cb799bac74ce4990fade5989902a6e1a9d/themes/Stencil/Styles/grid.css" media="all" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <link href="https://cdn4.bigcommerce.com/r-b894c2cb799bac74ce4990fade5989902a6e1a9d/themes/Stencil/Styles/responsive.css" media="all" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <link href="https://cdn4.bigcommerce.com/r-b894c2cb799bac74ce4990fade5989902a6e1a9d/themes/Stencil/Styles/font-awesome.css" media="all" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <link href="https://cdn4.bigcommerce.com/r-c6bdea2696c2b390db90de13e6bd8dc31e0f984a/javascript/superfish/css/store.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn4.bigcommerce.com/r-c6bdea2696c2b390db90de13e6bd8dc31e0f984a/javascript/jquery/plugins/imodal/imodal.css?87ceb" />

  <link href="https://cdn3.bigcommerce.com/s-4xqa0tnsba/stencil/39a119c0-217f-0135-4282-525400dfdca6/css/checkout-7a034520-27e5-0135-ba7c-525400970412.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">

  <!-- Tell the browsers about our RSS feeds -->

  <!-- Include visitor tracking code (if any) -->

  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn3.bigcommerce.com/r-c6bdea2696c2b390db90de13e6bd8dc31e0f984a/javascript/menudrop.js?"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn3.bigcommerce.com/r-c6bdea2696c2b390db90de13e6bd8dc31e0f984a/javascript/viewport.js?"></script>

  <!-- Theme bespoke js -->
  <script src="https://cdn3.bigcommerce.com/r-b894c2cb799bac74ce4990fade5989902a6e1a9d/themes/Stencil/js/common.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn3.bigcommerce.com/r-b894c2cb799bac74ce4990fade5989902a6e1a9d/themes/Stencil/js/jquery.autobox.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn3.bigcommerce.com/r-b894c2cb799bac74ce4990fade5989902a6e1a9d/themes/Stencil/js/init.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn3.bigcommerce.com/r-b894c2cb799bac74ce4990fade5989902a6e1a9d/themes/Stencil/js/jquery.uniform.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn3.bigcommerce.com/r-b894c2cb799bac74ce4990fade5989902a6e1a9d/themes/Stencil/js/main.js?"></script>

  <script>
    //<![CDATA[
    config.ShopPath = 'https://store-4xqa0tnsba.mybigcommerce.com';
    config.Email = '';
    config.AppPath = ''; // BIG-8939: Deprecated, do not use.
    config.FastCart = 1;
    config.ShowCookieWarning = !!0;
    var ThumbImageWidth = 190;
    var ThumbImageHeight = 285;
    //]]>
  </script>

  <script type="text/javascript">
    function beacon_deferred(beacon_api) {
      beacon_api.order.success('', 2993220, {
        "order": {
          "num": "52611501"
        },
        "customer": {
          "id": 3
        }
      });
      beacon_api.set_cookie_domain(".store-4xqa0tnsba.mybigcommerce.com");
      beacon_api.pageview('', 2993220, "order_success", {
        "order": {
          "num": "52611501"
        },
        "customer": {
          "id": 3
        }
      }, 'dfc98ec4-0f99-4e85-8686-0badb06c9a76', 'f1de836e-72f9-4f25-b331-6b83ca33785f');
    }

    (function() {
      var d = document,
        g = d.createElement('script'),
        s = d.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
      g.type = 'text/javascript';
      g.defer = g.async = true;
      g.src = 'https://cdn4.bigcommerce.com/r-c6bdea2696c2b390db90de13e6bd8dc31e0f984a/javascript/jirafe/beacon_api.js';
      s.parentNode.insertBefore(g, s);
    })();
  </script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn4.bigcommerce.com/r-c6bdea2696c2b390db90de13e6bd8dc31e0f984a/javascript/jquery/plugins/jquery.form.js?87ceb"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn4.bigcommerce.com/r-c6bdea2696c2b390db90de13e6bd8dc31e0f984a/javascript/jquery/plugins/imodal/imodal.js?87ceb"></script>

  <script type="text/javascript">
    (function() {
      window.bcanalytics || (window.bcanalytics = []), window.bcanalytics.methods = ["debug", "identify", "track",
        "trackLink", "trackForm", "trackClick", "trackSubmit", "page", "pageview", "ab", "alias", "ready", "group",
        "on", "once", "off", "initialize"
      ], window.bcanalytics.factory = function(a) {
        return function() {
          var b = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);
          return b.unshift(a), window.bcanalytics.push(b),
            window.bcanalytics
        }
      };
      for (var i = 0; i < window.bcanalytics.methods.length; i++) {
        var method = window.bcanalytics.methods[i];
        window.bcanalytics[method] = window.bcanalytics.factory(method)
      }
      window.bcanalytics.load = function() {
        var a = document.createElement("script");
        a.type = "text/javascript",
          a.async = !0, a.src = "https://cdn4.bigcommerce.com/r-c6bdea2696c2b390db90de13e6bd8dc31e0f984a/app/assets/js/vendor/bigcommerce/analytics.min.js";
        var b = document.getElementsByTagName("script")[0];
        b.parentNode.insertBefore(a, b)
      }, window.bcanalytics.SNIPPET_VERSION = "2.0.8", window.bcanalytics.load();
      bcanalytics.initialize({
        "Fornax": {
          "host": "https:\/\/analytics.bigcommerce.com",
          "cdn": "https:\/\/cdn4.bigcommerce.com\/r-c6bdea2696c2b390db90de13e6bd8dc31e0f984a\/app\/assets\/js\/vendor\/bigcommerce\/fornax.min.js",
          "defaultEventProperties": {
            "storeId": 999441665,
            "experiments": {
              "PROJECT-174.channel_twitter": "control",
              "PROJECT-331.pos_manager": "on",
              "PROJECT-632.square_export": "on",
              "PROJECT-756.channel_pinterest": "on",
              "PROJECT-756.pinterest_material_options": "control",
              "PROJECT-783.channel_facebook": "on",
              "PROJECT-783.channel_facebook.disconnect": "on",
              "PROJECT-1245.amazon-payments.registration.eu": "on",
              "PROJECT-1245.amazon-payments.registration.us": "on",
              "PROJECT-1493.custom_order_status_labels": "control",
              "OMNI-1010.channel_amazon.coming_soon": "on",
              "OMNI-913.channel_amazon": "on",
              "OMNI-2917.channel_buy_buttons": "on",
              "OMNI-2918.google_shopping": "control",
              "OMNI-1010.channel_ebay.coming_soon": "control",
              "OMNI-764.channel_ebay": "on",
              "OMNI-3167.channel_instagram.coming_soon": "on",
              "OMNI-900.channel_amazon.amazon_variants": "control",
              "OMNI-799.facebook_checkout": "on",
              "OMNI-2943.channel_facebook.refactor": "control",
              "OMNI-2999.products.cdn": "on",
              "OMNI-3354.omnichannel.cdn": "on",
              "BIG-29859.facebook_messenger_integration": "control",
              "CP-78.cp_click_tracking": "control",
              "PROJECT-1082.promote_ppec": "on",
              "BIG-28672.shipstation": "on",
              "PROJECT-871.dashboard_redesign": "on",
              "PROJECT-974.order_notification": "on",
              "ng-products": "control",
              "ng-add-edit-products": "control",
              "API-417.enable_api_oauth_account_creation": "on",
              "CRO-5.new_product_listing": "off",
              "CRO-16.left_align_buttons": "on",
              "CRO-8.getting-started-content-test": "on",
              "CRO-63.separate-design-options": "off",
              "PROJECT-1441.dashboard.store_performance_channels": "on",
              "PROJECT-1413.PinterestProductListings": "control",
              "CRO-83.create_test_order_onboarding_card": "control",
              "CP-860.switch_stores": "on",
              "PROJECT-1413.PinterestChannelServiceAuth": "control",
              "CRO-46.upload-logo-design": "control",
              "CP-1284.search-ui": "control",
              "PROJECT-1522.google_customer_reviews": "control",
              "PROJECT-976.braintree.visa.checkout": "control",
              "CP-1252.self_help.phase2": "control",
              "DATA-2896.ng-analytics.enable": "control"
            }
          },
          "defaultContext": {
            "source": "Bigcommerce Storefront"
          },
          "anonymousId": "f1de836e-72f9-4f25-b331-6b83ca33785f"
        }
      });
    })();

    var BCData = {};
  </script>


  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn4.bigcommerce.com/r-c6bdea2696c2b390db90de13e6bd8dc31e0f984a/javascript/quicksearch.js"></script>
  <!--[if lt IE 9]>
 <script src="https://cdn3.bigcommerce.com/r-b894c2cb799bac74ce4990fade5989902a6e1a9d/themes/Stencil/js/html5shiv.js"></script>
 <![endif]-->
</head>

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn3.bigcommerce.com/r-c6bdea2696c2b390db90de13e6bd8dc31e0f984a/javascript/jquery/plugins/jCarousel/jCarousel.js?"></script>

<body>
  <div id="DrawerMenu">
    <div class="inner">
      <div class="CategoryList" id="SideCategoryList">
        <h3>Categories</h3>
        <div class="BlockContent">
          <div class="SideCategoryListFlyout">
            <ul class="sf-menu sf-horizontal">
              <li><a href="http://shop.modassystems.com/tomball-top/">Tomball</a>
                <ul>
                  <li><a href="http://shop.modassystems.com/program/tomball/devices/">Devices</a>
                    <ul>
                      <li><a href="http://shop.modassystems.com/program/tomball/devices/android/">Android</a></li>
                      <li><a href="http://shop.modassystems.com/program/tomball/devices/iphones/">iPhones</a></li>
                      <li><a href="http://shop.modassystems.com/program/tomball/devices/basic-phones/">Basic Phones</a></li>
                      <li><a href="http://shop.modassystems.com/program/tomball/devices/tablets/">Tablets</a></li>
                      <li><a href="http://shop.modassystems.com/program/tomball/devices/mifi/">MiFi</a></li>

                    </ul>
                  </li>
                  <li><a href="http://shop.modassystems.com/tomball/equipment-protection/">Equipment Protection</a></li>

                </ul>
              </li>
              <li><a href="http://shop.modassystems.com/education/">Education</a>
                <ul>
                  <li><a href="http://shop.modassystems.com/education/tomballisdtx/">Tomball ISD</a>
                    <ul>
                      <li><a href="http://shop.modassystems.com/education/tomball-isd/devices/">Devices</a>
                        <ul>
                          <li><a href="http://shop.modassystems.com/mgdpmtplt/tomball-isd/devices/iphones/">iPhones</a></li>
                          <li><a href="http://shop.modassystems.com/hidden/education/tomball-isd/devices/basic-phones/">Basic Phones</a></li>
                          <li><a href="http://shop.modassystems.com/mgdpmtplt/tomball-isd/devices/android/">Android</a></li>
                          <li><a href="http://shop.modassystems.com/hidden/education/tomball-isd/devices/mifi/">MiFi</a></li>

                        </ul>
                      </li>
                      <li><a href="http://shop.modassystems.com/education/tomball-isd/equipment-protection/">Equipment Protection</a></li>
                      <li><a href="http://shop.modassystems.com/tisdtxbyod/">BYOD</a></li>

                    </ul>
                  </li>

                </ul>
              </li>
              <li><a href="http://shop.modassystems.com/kippdc/">KIPP DC</a>
                <ul>
                  <li><a href="http://shop.modassystems.com/modas-mobile-technology-programs/kipp-dc/phones/">Phones</a>
                    <ul>
                      <li><a href="http://shop.modassystems.com/kipp-dc/phones/ios/">iOS</a></li>
                      <li><a href="http://shop.modassystems.com/kipp-dc/phones/android/">Android</a></li>

                    </ul>
                  </li>

                </ul>
              </li>

            </ul>

          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="Block Moveable Panel" id="SideShopByBrand" style="display:none;"></div>
      <div class="Block Moveable Panel" id="SideCategoryShopByPrice" style="display:none;"></div>
      <div class="AdditionalInformationList Moveable Panel slist" id="SideAdditionalInformation">
        <h3>Additional Information</h3>
        <div class="BlockContent">
          <ul class="treeview">
            <li><a href="/">Home</a></li>
          </ul>
          <ul class="pages-menu sf-menu sf-horizontal sf-js-enabled">
            <li class=" ">
              <a href="http://shop.modassystems.com/about-us/"><span>About Us</span></a>
            </li>
            <li class=" ">
              <a href="http://shop.modassystems.com/contact-us/"><span>Contact Us</span></a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="AccountNavigationList Moveable Panel slist" id="SideAccountNavigation">
        <h3>Site Information</h3>
        <div class="BlockContent js-side-account-menu">
          <!-- Fill with content from TopMenu -->
        </div>
      </div>
      <script>
        (function($, window) {
          'use strict';

          var bcTheme = window.bcTheme || {};
          bcTheme.mobile = bcTheme.mobile || {};

          var MobileAccountMenu = function MobileAccountMenu() {};

          MobileAccountMenu.prototype.init = function init(selector) {
            this.$element = $(selector);

            this.cloneTopMenu();
            this.setCurrencyConvertor();
            this.bindEvents();

          };

          MobileAccountMenu.prototype.cloneTopMenu = function cloneTopMenu() {
            // Cloning from top menu as Globals don't work down here.
            var $topMenuClone = $('.TopMenu ul').clone(),
              $phoneNumber = $('<a />', {
                'text': $('.js-drawermenu-store-phone-container').find('.phoneIcon').text(),
                'href': 'tel:' + $('.js-drawermenu-store-phone-container').find('.js-drawermenu-store-phone').text()
              });
            //Modify the cloned menu to make phone clickable and hide stuff we don't need
            $topMenuClone.find('.phoneIcon').replaceWith($phoneNumber);
            $topMenuClone.find('.js-drawermenu-cart').remove();
            //append new menu to drawer
            this.$element.append($topMenuClone);
          };

          MobileAccountMenu.prototype.setCurrencyConvertor = function setCurrencyConvertor() {
            this.$mobileCurrencyConverter = this.$element.find('.js-drawermenu-currency-converter');
            this.$mobileSelectedCurrency = this.$mobileCurrencyConverter.find('.selected-currency');
            this.$mobileCurrencyList = this.$mobileCurrencyConverter.find('.CurrencyList');
          };

          MobileAccountMenu.prototype.bindEvents = function bindEvents() {
            var that = this;

            this.$mobileSelectedCurrency.on('click', function(e) {
              e.preventDefault();
              that.$mobileSelectedCurrency.toggleClass('open');
              that.$mobileCurrencyList.toggleClass('open');
            });
          };

          bcTheme.mobile.accountMenu = new MobileAccountMenu();

          window.bcTheme = window.bcTheme || bcTheme;

        }(jQuery, window));

        $(function() {
          bcTheme.mobile.accountMenu.init('.js-side-account-menu');
        });
      </script>
    </div>
  </div>
  <script>
    //<![CDATA[
    $(function() {

      //Drawer Subnavigation Accordion
      $('#DrawerMenu li ul').addClass('drawer-subcat');
      $('#DrawerMenu .drawer-subcat').prev('a').after('<span class="subcat-expand"></span>');
      $('#DrawerMenu .subcat-expand').click(function() {
        $(this).next('.drawer-subcat').toggleClass('expanded');
        $(this).toggleClass('subcat-expanded');
      });
    });
    //]]>
  </script>


  <div class="page">
    <div class="header">
      <div class="inner">
        <div id="AjaxLoading">
          <div class="ajax-loader">
            <img src="https://cdn3.bigcommerce.com/r-b894c2cb799bac74ce4990fade5989902a6e1a9d/themes/Stencil/images/loader.png" alt="" />&nbsp;Loading... Please wait...
          </div>
        </div>
        <div id="Header">
          <div class="inner">
            <div class="header-logo">
              <div id="LogoContainer">
                <h1><a href="http://shop.modassystems.com/"><span class="Logo1stWord">Modas</span> Systems</a></h1>
              </div>

            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="main">
      <div class="inner">
        <div class="checkout-banner">
          <a href="https://store-4xqa0tnsba.mybigcommerce.com">Continue shopping on Modas Systems</a>
        </div>
        <div class="Content ExpressCheckoutBlock" id="LayoutColumn2">
          <div class="Block">
            <h1 class="TitleHeading">Thanks for Your Order, john!</h1>
```

Comment: $('.classname').hide(); ?

Comment: Can you provide us with some of your code? Also, please tell us what you tried, but failed to use sucessfully.

Comment: css: `.hidden {display:none !important;}` js: `$('.classname').addClass('hidden');`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all you can put this code anywhere in between your html code.
Step 1-include or embed the file which interprets the jquery syntax.So you can write it in "head" tag like this

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

That's the online version of Jquery so make sure you are connected to internet.
Step 2-Make a script tag to write you jquery code like this

```
<script>
function rmv(){
$(".classnameofelementtohide").hide();
}
</script>
```

Now the last step is to call the function when the button is clicked,so the button code should be like this:

```
<button onclick="rmv()">Click to submit your order online</button>
```

Comment: wow - that's awesome! i dig that - only it's not a button - i'm trying to make it so when said script see's the class - checkbox-banner - i want it to be hidden. :-( i'm sorry i'm so lame with this stuff.

Comment: I am sorry to say but i could not understand even a single word what you just said in your comment.Please elaborate!

Answer (score 1):

Just use a simple `$('.classname').hide();`, like Matthew Broderick suggested.

In my example, I've set the function to be called on a button press, but you can change that.

```js
function removeLines() {
  $('#line1, #line2').hide();
}
```

```css
.container {
  height: 200px;
  background-color: blue;
}
#line1 {
  background-color: red;
}
#line2 {
  background-color: yellow;
}
#line3 {
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div id="line1">Line 1</div>
  <div id="line2">Line 2</div>
  <div id="line3">Line 3</div>
  <button onclick="removeLines()">Click me to remove lines 1 and 2</button>
</div>
```

Comment: man - that's awesome that you can write something like that. so quickly too! i'll get there one day!!! for now - if i can get away with $('.classname').hide(); - i'd be good to go - i just a) don't know where to put it and is this the proper syntax? 

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js">$('.checkout-banner').hide();</script>

Answer (score 1):

To hide a class in jquery use this code

```
$(".classname").hide();
```

I guess you are a newbie in jquery.By the way this should be written in

```
$("#idofbutton").click(function(){
$(".classname").hide();
})
```

Here "idofbutton" is the button which on clicking an online order submission is placed as you said.
Hope it helps!!!

Comment: yes - TOTAL newbie - i'm fairly dangerous in HTML and CSS and a TINY big of jQuery - but i've never written anything from scratch. 

i can't provide "code" per say - bc i'm not sure where the code is coming from - this is what renders though when the page has been pushed live.